# Buscar una palabra en una cadena de tamaño predeterminado

Tags: regex

Necesito armar una expresión regular tal que de como válida una cadena si en esa cadena se encuentra un cierto texto que no sea case sensitive y que esta cadena no supere un tamaño.

Por ejemplo: la palabra "como" y máximo 15 caracteres

```
Valido : Como esto  
Valido : a como como
Valido : esto como todo
Inválido : Este como no es válido
```

Yo probé lo siguiente:

`.*como.{0,10}$` : pero solo me toma que el máximo sea el final y puedo tener cualquier cantidad delante

`.{0,10}como.{0,10}$` : esto casi funciona pero, no me toma case sensitive  y me puedo pasar de la cantidad o no dejarme la cantidad total que quiero.

No le doy a exactamente lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular, en donde verifica que la longitud sea de 15 caracteres como máximo contando las letras y espacios, ya sea mayúscula o minúscula:

```js
function verificarCadena(texto) {
  regex = /^(?=.[a-zA-Z\s]{0,15}$).*como.*$/g;
  
  if (regex.test(texto)) {
    return 'Es válido';
  } else {
    return 'No es válido';
  }
}

console.log(verificarCadena('Como esto'));
console.log(verificarCadena('a como como'));
console.log(verificarCadena('esto como todo'));
console.log(verificarCadena('Este como no es válido'));
```

Comment: GRacias. También funciona

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto:

```
^(?=.{0,15}$).*como.*
```

y lo del case sensitive va con las opciones que se usan normalmente después de la barra delimitadora **/**, como **g** de global, o **m** de multilínea... pues para el case insensitive seria **i**.

En [este enlace](https://regex101.com/r/b08Pna/1) puedes verlo en acción y con las explicaciones pertinentes en la casilla que aparece a mano derecha bajo el título EXPLANATION (en inglés).

Comment: Excelente. Anda perfecto